# TextBox onchange when setting value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, textbox, onchange, jquery-events

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#text').live('change', function() {
            alert('hello');
        });
        $('#button').live('click', function() {
            $('#text').val('some text');
        });
    });  

    <div>
        <input type="button" id="button" value="Click Me" />
        <input type="text" id="text" />
    </div>
```

How can I make the `change` function on the textbox trigger when I click the button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) (the shortcut) or [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), like this:

```
$('#button').live('click', function() {
  $('#text').val('some text').change();
});
```

Or this:

```
$('#button').live('click', function() {
  $('#text').val('some text').trigger('change');
});
```

Either method works to trigger any [`change` event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/change/) you've added, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/XE6gu/).