# Trigger a page change based on a textbox edit

Tags: javascript, c#, textbox, dom-events

My problem is that, I want to call a code behind function from a JS. So that I can implement TextBox on Click event. I am NEW in JS so bear with me on this one...What I heard is that from the client side scripting you cannot call anything to the server (code behind). Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function callCodeBehind() {
       <% txtAgentName_TextChanged(); %>
       }

 </script>
```

This is my Textbox:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtAgentName" runat="server" Onclick = "callCodeBehind()"></asp:TextBox>
```

This is my code behind:

```
 protected void txtAgentName_TextChanged()
    {

    }
```

This function is getting fired on `Page_Load()`, which I don't want it to.
All I want is that to call this function `txtAgentName_TextChanged()` when user clicks on `txtAgentName` textbox.

Help!

Comment: Please explain your use case better.  It is still not clear exactly what you want to do.  I'M SURE THERE IS A SIMPLE WAY TO DO IT but you are not saying exactly what you want to do.  Once we know what you want to do we can tell you how.

Comment: I'm sure that what you DON'T want to do is click a button.  Please explain your use case -- A use case is how the user will interact with the web site and what they will see.  Don't decide how the code will work yet.  Use case is what we need.

Comment: @hogan Simple way to mix server-side & client-side? In client-side javascript, it is easy to get a variable from server-side asp script (var jsArray = new Array( <%=aspArray%> ). But vice versa, how would you do that?

Comment: @ Chris and Hogan: I updated my answer but that code behind function is firing up on Page_Load().

Comment: @Chris - There are many thing @Mayank could be trying to do -- each with a different solution.  He could want to submit the form, he could want to pre-populate the textbox, he could want to create a pick list, he could want to audit page use, etc etc -- all of them would have a different answer.  Unless we know what he wants to do we can't answer the question so he can understand as a beginner.

Comment: ok we are getting somewhere -- you want to do something when the text box changes -- what do you want to do in the code behind that you can't wait for the form to be submitted?

Comment: @Mayank -- Chris' suggestions don't make sense -- they will be called when the page is rendered.  Please explain what the code behind needs to do when the text changes and why you can't just use the text box's onchange on a regular form submit.

Comment: @Hogan: I want run a query in code behind and I want to update another textbox which is in the form.

Comment: OK!  The best way to do this is with ajax.  I would also suggest using jQuery as it will be easier for the beginner.  Some of the answers have links to example AJAX -- take a look at those.  You would call the AJAX based on the javascript OnChange event.

Comment: @Hogan: Thank you. Can you provide me with some link?

Comment: Changing values in text box are covered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202716/textbox-onchange-when-setting-value-with-javascript-jquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911832/how-to-track-change-in-textbox-using-jquery . For AJAX help look at amit's answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, you can use page methods. Check below articles for exact instructions.

[Using Page Methods in ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Using_Page_Methods_in_ASPNET_AJAX.aspx)

[Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp). Check out the sample in the link.

Comment: I have AJAX.dll installed in my solution. What should I do from AJAX?

Comment: @Mayank Raj That is a whole new question on its own.  Are you using Visual Studio .NET?

Comment: Yes Chris. I am using VS2010. Pls chk my updated answer. Updated with code.

Comment: Nice, it has some extra goodies for dealing with AJAX. Check out this link - http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1276/call-server-side-method-from-client-side-using-script-manager/

Answer (score 1):

You CAN call code behind from server using AJAX and jQuery library, just google it. e.g.
http://blogs.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

A second issue is that the btn.click() will not work cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert a code behind method like this:

```
<% method(); &>
```

Comment: Can  you provide me with some code. Sorry I am NEW in JS stuff man.

Comment: you can also call methods from the html directly.

Comment: eg: <div><% writeDiv(); %> </div>    private void writeDiv(){ Response.Write("Hi, this a test");}

Comment: @Eric: I implemented that, but it is calling that code behind function on Page_Load(). Not firing when I am clicking on tat TextBox. Updated my answer. Pls check.

Comment: <input type="text" onClick="callCodeBehind" />

Comment: Nops Erik. Input type is a Textbox. I want to do something when the text box changes -- I want to run a query in my code behind, I can't wait for the form to be submitted?

Comment: try jquery: $("#textbox").change(function(){<% query();&>});

Comment: Where should I write this in my UI?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

      $("#txtAgentName").change(function(){<% txtAgentName_TextChanged();%>});

</script>

Comment: Still my function is not firing up. It is firing on Page_Load()